# Telnet client is missing in Windows 7 features turn on and off

Tags: windows-7, windows

On my Windows 7 PC, telnet command is not working. I tried all the steps mentioned [in the following article](https://www.wikihow.com/Activate-Telnet-in-Windows-7) but none of them are working for me.

Most of the article suggested enabling Telnet client on from “Turn Windows Features” on and off. But in my case, that option is missing from the list.

[image: Screen Shot of My Turn Windows Features on and off]

Comment: Try using an Admin account.

Comment: Try via an elevated shell: `dism /online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:TelnetClient`

Comment: @MichaelNancarrow. I tried but it is giving error:  Error: 740
Elevated permissions are required to run DISM.
Use an elevated command prompt to complete these tasks.

Comment: @Sudash Yes - hence why I stated to use an elevated prompt! Are you not an administrator on this account?

Comment: have you used vLite to or other tool to reduce Win7 size?

Comment: @magicandre1e981: I am not sure, but I guess you are right. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your account must have Administrator access. Otherwise, you will not be able to enable/disable the **Telnet Client**, or the **Telnet Server**.

If you are using an account with Administrator access, you should have the following options:

[image]